# I am facing an error while installing TestNG in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium, testng-eclipse

I am trying to install the TestNG in my Eclipse Oxygen using the following steps:

1. Launch Eclipse
2. Under help select *Eclipse Marketplace...*
3. Searched for `TestNG`
4. If I click on *Install* I get the error message `Unexpected features while verifying features java.language.NullpointerException.`

Please help.

How can I install TestNG on my current Eclipse?

Comment: start eclipse with clean and try once or download new eclipse if eclipse build is corrupted.

Comment: please read the troubleshooting doc for installation issue: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.md